# How to change wordpress page link via ajax?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, url-rewriting, permalinks

After days of searching the information about "permalinks" I managed how to change post/pages permalinks via post_type_link/page_link filters and add_rewrite_rule function. But what I want is to change page url after clicking on a page's button (and so I could transfer some query_vars values may be). The page souldn't reload. I tried to place 'page_link' filter in function that receives ajax request, but it didn't work.

By the way, why when I change post's permalink via 'post_type_link' filter I can see the link changes in the admin pannel (on post edit page), but when I change page's permalink via 'page_link' filter I see changes only when click on the link in the admin pannel(on page edit page url stays unchanged)?

Answer (score 0):

Damn, sorry, I should think just a little bit more. I can change just browser address bar and history via 'window.history.pushState("string", "Title", "newUrl")', and then just add new rewrite rule for this url.